# Recursive flood fill not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, flood-fill

Here is my code. I don't think my logic is wrong but if it is please tell me:

```
function floodrecursive()
{
    let x=0;
    let y=0;
    
    canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;
        
        var basecolor = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
        //alert(basecolor);
        var fillcolor = document.getElementById("colorinput").value;
        
        flood(c, x, y, basecolor, fillcolor);
    });
}
    
function flood(c, x, y, basecolor, fillcolor)
{
    var currentpixel = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    if (currentpixel === basecolor)
    {
        putpixel(c, x, y, fillcolor);
        flood(c, x+1, y, basecolor, fillcolor);
        flood(c, x-1, y, basecolor, fillcolor);
        flood(c, x, y+1, basecolor, fillcolor);
        flood(c, x, y-1, basecolor, fillcolor);
    }
}

function putpixel(c, x, y, fillcolor)
{
    c.fillStyle = "#" + fillcolor;
    c.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}
```

I tried putting the `flood` and `putpixel` functions inside the `floodrecursive` function, or inside the `addEventListener` but it still won't work. I don't know why.

I already have this function:

```
window.onload=function() {covercanvas()};
function covercanvas()
{
    c.fillStyle="plum";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, 1030, 430);
}
```

so that the `basecolor` isn't transparent. And the `alert(basecolor)` works too so I don't know what's going wrong here.

Here's the HTML:

```
<button class="floodbutton" onclick="floodrecursive()"> Flood fill </button>

<input type="text" id="colorinput"></input>
```

How I expected the code to work is that after I draw on the canvas, put the hexa value of a color in the input box, then click the button, and click the canvas again, it should start flood filling.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]: _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Sorry I'm a bit noob. I don't really understand you. 1. By boundary-check you mean like this: `x: e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft`? But `x = e.offsetX` works fine tho. 2. So I shouldn't use `===`? I tried `==` but also didn't work. 3. I have to use recursive algorithm, it's part of the requirement :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a `hexAtoRGBA` function and now it works perfectly. But I still... kinda don't understand. Here's the updated code:

```
function floodrecursive()
{
    let x=0;
    let y=0;
    
    canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;
        
        var basecolor = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
        var base = hexAToRGBA(basecolor);
        var fillcolor = document.getElementById("colorinput").value;
        
        flood(c, x, y, base, fillcolor);
    });
}
    
function flood(c, x, y, base, fillcolor)
{
    var currentpixel = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    var currentpix = hexAToRGBA(currentpixel);
    if (currentpix === base)
    {
        putpixel(c, x, y, fillcolor);
        flood(c, x+1, y, base, fillcolor);
        flood(c, x-1, y, base, fillcolor);
        flood(c, x, y+1, base, fillcolor);
        flood(c, x, y-1, base, fillcolor);
    }
}

function hexAToRGBA(h) {
  let r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 1;

  if (h.length == 4) {
    r = "0x" + h[1] + h[1];
    g = "0x" + h[2] + h[2];
    b = "0x" + h[3] + h[3];
    a = "0x" + h[4] + h[4];

  } else if (h.length == 8) {
    r = "0x" + h[1] + h[2];
    g = "0x" + h[3] + h[4];
    b = "0x" + h[5] + h[6];
    a = "0x" + h[7] + h[8];
  }
  a = +(a / 255).toFixed(3);

  return "rgba(" + +r + "," + +g + "," + +b + "," + a + ")";
}
```

The thing I don't understand is, the `c.getImageData` already returns the value in RGBA format, so why does it work only after I've added the `hexAtoRGBA` function for both `base` and `currentpix`? They're both using `c.getImageData` so they're already comparing RGBA, right?